# JSF commandbutton onclick event not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am trying to use a normal JSF commandbutton instead of submit button. For that I am using this

```
<h:commandButton value="clickme" type="button" onclick="window.print();"/>
```

But normal raw html works

```
<input type="button" name="demo" value="clickme" onclick="window.print();" />
```

When I remove the window.print() from the onclick the button is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`onclick="window.print(); return false;"`

As per [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1720878?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: I have used the same : <h:commandButton type="submit" value="clickme" onclick="window.print(); return false;"/> The button itself is not rendered in the browser and thrown error in browser :error on line 5 at column 139: Attribute onclick redefined

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<h:commandButton value="clickme" type="button" onclick="javascript:window.print();return false;"/>
```

Comment: Which jsf version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In `JSF 1.2` `type=button` is not supported. So your choices are only either `type=submit`or `type=reset`. Use `JSF 2` if you want to use `button` type in your commandbutton component.